# Is that correct way that this code i using (remove file/unlink) in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, blogs, unlink

I want to ask you guys about my code **in my php update form.**
I use **unlink($file_Path)** to Remove my image file in my folder & my server  *and that work fine!*

So I wonder when using **"unlink($file_Path)"** to removing an image, In my php page it show me an **"Image File Icon "** when there was no picture *(The image file was removed)* 
 But it show me like that *(Image file Icon)* Because, I though It still has a **some value** **(my value = "../filename.jpg")**

so I put "**value=" "/**" *(None Value to Reset a Value)*
*example* :
 `<input type="hidden" name="newSubimage1" value=""/>`
*and that work fine* when I use with **"!empty($ro.."**

*example* :

```
if (isset($row['subimage1']) && !empty($row['subimage1']))
 {
    echo "<img src='../images/images_products/".$row['subimage1']."'>";  
 } else {
    echo "No Image Here"; }
```

`

to not show an "Image File Icon"
Is that a correct way ? that I used to **Removing file / Not display an Image File  Icon**  or you has any easy way or the best way that you want to suggest me.

**thanks**

Comment: I think it's ok, but you can add the missing image file checking condition, in addition

Comment: thanks you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$image_file_ext = array('jpg', 'png', 'bmp');
$file_ext = pathinfo($row['subimage1'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if (isset($row['subimage1']) && !empty($row['subimage1']) && in_array($file_ext, $image_file_ext))
{
    echo "<img src='../images/images_products/".$row['subimage1']."'>";  
} else {
    echo "No Image Here"; 
}
```